unity, how to install android sdk, jdk, ndk on MacOS?
I have installed unity 2023.3.33f1 to MacBook with supporting of Android build, but it installed without Android SDK, ndk and openjdk. How to install them?

for some reason (at least on windows) we dont get the option to remove them, only add.. best answer would be to remove the whole lot, then install only the bits you need - if its that important
